# Engine stoped working

Tags: engine, toyota, leak, camry

I was driving my car to work today where it stopped working. It happened when I tried to drive it after I stopped for traffic light. Luckily some people helped me over to push it to the side road where it is currently parked at. Every time I try to start the engine fluid comes under the hood. Can you help me figure out what could be the problem.

EDIT: Recently I have changed the coolant and the color of the fluid looks just like coolant. Plus I have checked the engine oil it looks bad. The leak only happens only when I try to start the engine.

[image]

The second picture is taken from the left side of the tire:

[image]

Comment: @NumairAidroos link to video https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0RuOnIGWnE_ay1uRmw2RmtWa2s

Comment: Like I said earlier this would require further inspection. Question is would you be able to change the water pump? If diagnosis points to it?

Comment: When you changed the coolant did you remove/release the bleeder valve? Was a new one used later?

Comment: Given its location this seems like tranny fluid

Comment: Comment the year of manufacture.

Comment: Are you getting any warning lights on the dashboard? The car would probably still start if it was just leaking coolant, but would show overheating.

Comment: You never came back.

Answer (score 1):

Finding the source of the leak is always challenging. While noting where the fluid lands is useful in many cases, fluid can land on other pipes and suspension parts and actually fall to the ground a distance from the source.

Once the type of fluid is identified, then the pipes and components of those systems can be inspected and then the source of the problem identified and corrected.

For most vehicles, all you need to do to check the levels is to have the bonnet up with the ignition switched off. There are some vehicles, mostly with auto transmission, that require the engine to be running (and cycled through the gears in some cases) to be able to ascertain the correct level.

Answer (score -3):

Just put the key in the ignition over to 'on' position. 
Do not attempt to start it yet.

1. Check the coolant level in the reservoir
2. Engine oil level on dipstick
3. Tranny oil level on it's dipstick (if provided)
4. Check brake fluid levels
5. To be on the safe side check the washer fluid level
6. Power steering fluid as well (just an afterthought)

*I'll edit my answer based on your comments to the aforementioned levels of fluid.

Now mark the level of each fluid with a snapshot, while you attempt to start.

I think it's the power steering system and transmission seals that are leaking here. [image]